# Prevent PHP script to access into filesystem

Tags: php

I would like to run my custom php script only if script has not contain any function which can access to other scripts.

This is my solution:

```
function validateScript($data)
{
    $match = null;
    if(preg_match('/error_reporting|require|include|file_get_contents|glob|file|fgets|fread|dearfile|ini_set|system|proc_open|iframe|frame|show_source|readfile|passthru|pdo|mysql|phpinfo|session|server|var_dump|var_export|echo|exec|eval|popen|telnet|\$\$|\${\$/i', $data, $match)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

$script = 'customscript.php';
$data = file_get_contents($script)

if(validateScript($data)) {
    include $script;
}
```

I am not sure if this is good solution or if exists more secured way how to do it?

Comment: Stop this idea you open yourself way to much to get attacked here by hackers.. Not even the PHP's XML parser classes are safe to allow to be running because off XML External Entity (XXE) attack vectors.

Comment: ... which also can access the file system..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to run my custom php script only if script has not contain any function which can access to other scripts.

That's a description of a solution - it would help if you explained what the problem is.

There are a lot of ommissions from your list and it is trivial to bypass the mechanisms you have put in place to prevent access.

For example (there's lot of other ways of avoiding the checks) I can run any of the functions you've blacklisted simply by:

```
foreach ($_GET['cmd'] as $key=>$fn) 
  call_user_func($fn, unserialize($_GET['args'][$key]);
```

If you really want to write a secure sandbox with no disk I/O then you have at least 2 years of research and practice ahead of you. Hint: don't even start by trying to parse the script contents.

Comment: "If you really want to write a secure sandbox with no disk I/O then you have at least 2 years of research and practice ahead of you" What about PHP.ini 's setting `disable_functions`, most simple and secure way out off the box to make a "sandbox" going and it does not take 2 years of research.

Comment: besides `unserialize()` with user controled input can cause PHP Object Injection (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection)  not 100% save to use.. The attack is pretty hard to pull off tho because the classes most have a __wakeup or __destruct function and the attacker needs to know the code.. Not impossible if the attacker sees you are using opensource librarys/software with __wakeup  or __destruct functions in it.

Comment: it's even warned about it in the manual "Warning

Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize() regardless of the options value of allowed_classes. Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this. Use a safe, standard data interchange format such as JSON" http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: @Raymond: you are doing the same thing as step; assuming you control the behaviour of user submitted code by blacklisting. It only defeats someone less smart than you are.

Comment: Atleast the PHP blacklisting "sandbox" (disable_functions in the PHP.ini) is more secure than programming your own blacklist functions.. Right?. Besides there are many more ways to get access to the file system. But i deleted mine answer because there are way to much things in PHP which can be used to get access to the filesystem including XML External Entity (XXE) attack vectors.